# Type converting a string to a multiline version

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, multilinestring

I have

```
 string subquery="cmd cmd";
```

I need

```
string query = @"asd 
asd  asd

asd asd
"+ MakeMultiline(subquery) + @"asd asd asd
asd asd where id=@id";
```

Possible without changing the declaration of subquery string?

I need this, because it gives unfinished string literal error when I try.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean - we don't know what `MakeMultiline` does, or where you're getting the error. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What is the definition of `MakeMultiline` method?

Comment: Its not real, I placed just for example. Tried with only the string literal. Real string query is pages long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Environment.NewLine or use \n \r\n.

Example:

```
string query = "asd \n asd  asd \n asd asd"+ MakeMultiline(subquery) +
 "asd asd asd \n asd asd where id=@id";
```

Dont use verbatim string by using the @, unless you want to define the escape sequence twice.